# SNBC BTP-R180II as Java POS Printer -> How?

Tags: java, printing, javapos

A SNBC BTP-R180II printer was dropped into my lap, and I am trying to use is via Javas PosPrinter library.
Problem is: I fail.
For Epson-Printers, things work: via ADK-Setup they receive a logical name which I can use to communicate -> That works.
The BTP-R180II is properly working with the computer -> PrinterUtilities send prints just fine.
I have used SNBC'S OPOS ADK to give the BTP-R180II a logical name; no success to then talk to it via JavaPos. SNBC's javaPos-Installer fails to help in any way, the help-file that came with it is empty of any actual text. My GoogleFoo Fails there, too, as I cannot find a manual that would hint at any commandline-options that would be helpful.
I am on Windows10, may that be a problem?